# How to share a file efficiently that is constantly changing?

Tags: file, share

Simple question:

What is the best way to share a file (with lots of people) that is being updated on a regular basis (most likely, daily)? I thought about using torrents but I'm not sure this is the best option because you can't update torrents so I'd be forced to upload a different torrent every time.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a version control system, like [git](http://git-scm.com). This is part of what version control was invented for. There are several good websites which will host your project, too. One popular one is [github](https://github.com).

Comment: I thought about it but github limits the size of the file, right?

Comment: Yes, github has a limit. It's a soft limit, but they're ask you to be "polite". It's ~1Gb. https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota

Comment: bitbucket, gitorious, and many others host git repos, though. Not to mention mercurial and bazaar.

Comment: I think that's enough. In any case, I could create other repository because the data I'd like to share have separable entries.

Comment: Ah. Note that github actually reccomends dropbox for some types of files. Might be okay, but I'm a vcs fanatic, myself.

Comment: @jpaugh is that like a dyslexic cvs?

Comment: Interesting. I love Dropbox but I wouldn't be comfortable depending on it for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a legal share (meaning you own the copyrights), you could always host your own domain with collocated server hosting if you're expecting a lot of traffic. Most hosting companies have a plan with unlimited bandwidth for cheap these days in a shared hosting environment if collocation is out of the question. If you need a lot of bandwidth you can look into services from companies like [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/) that do this sort of thing on a commercial level. If you're creating an open source project, then you can use [sourceforge.net](http://www.sourceforge.net), and [github](https://github.com/) like @jpaugh suggested.

You might also check out a service like [Mirrorcreator](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/) for sharing through things like RapidShare.

Comment: It's legal to share, but since this data should be available for everyone at all times, I don't want to deal with hosting myself.

Comment: If it were illegal, he couldn't share it at all! :-)

Comment: No harm in under-generalizing.